# Detect when input has a 'readonly' attribute

Tags: jquery

I want to throw an alert when an input has a 'readonly' attribute. I have tried this:

```
  if($('input').attr('readonly') == 'readonly'){

    alert("foo");
  }
```

I think that 'if' is not even the best way to do it.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

fastest way is to use the `.is()` jQuery function.

```
if ( $('input').is('[readonly]') ) { }
```

using `[readonly]` as a selector simply checks if the attribute is defined on your element. if you want to check for a value, you can use something like this instead:

```
if ( $('input').is('[readonly="somevalue"]') ) { }
```

Comment: I am trying to prevent a postback only if it's read only mode. I have an asp.net page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351993/how-to-disable-enter-key-when-a-asp-net-textarea-is-in-readonly-mode

Comment: This helps me to reset ajax based form to its default based on its attributes. reverse of `is` = `not`

Answer (score 32):

Since JQuery 1.6, always use .prop()
Read why here: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
if($('input').prop('readonly')){ }
```

.prop() can also be used to set the property

```
$('input').prop('readonly',true);

$('input').prop('readonly',false);
```

Answer (score 11):

what about javascript without jQuery ?

for any input that you can get with or without jQuery, just :

```
input.readOnly
```

note : mind camelCase

Comment: wanted to be done under ANGULAR (simple things) thing, took several hours to come here! Thanks for mind, cameCase.

Answer (score 5):

Check the current value of your "readonly" attribute, if it's "false" (a string) or empty (undefined or "") then it's not readonly.

```
$('input').each(function() {
    var readonly = $(this).attr("readonly");
    if(readonly && readonly.toLowerCase()!=='false') { // this is readonly
        alert('this is a read only field');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the attribute selector and then test the length:

```
$('input[readonly]').length == 0 // --> ok
$('input[readonly]').length > 0  // --> not ok
```

Answer (score 3):

Try a simple way:

```
if($('input[readonly="readonly"]')){
   alert("foo");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if($('input').attr('readonly') == undefined){
    alert("foo");
}
```

if it is not there it will be `undefined` in js

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla/pure javascript you can check as following -

```
var field = document.querySelector("input[name='fieldName']");
if(field.readOnly){
 alert("foo");
}
```