# How to disable ENTER key when a asp.net textarea is in readonly mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

ASP.net:

```
<textarea id="taskNotes" runat="server" class="taskNotes" rows="10" style=""></textarea>
```

HTML generated ASP.net TextArea:

```
<textarea name="ctl00$ContentMain$taskNotes" class="taskNotes" id="ContentMain_taskNotes" style="" rows="10" readOnly="readonly"/>
```

How can I disable the ENTER key from executing when the textarea has the focus and readonly.

I tried the following but wasn't able to complete:

```
$('input[class=taskNotes]').keydown(function (e) {
    if (('.taskNotes')) { // '.is()` is not populating in VS for me to complete...
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

Use this to prevent enter key

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('keydown', '.taskNotes[readonly]', function(e){
        if (e.which === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Or as an alternative, use this to prevent focus of the element altogether:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $(document).on('focus', '.taskNotes[readonly]', function(e){
        $(this).blur();
    });
});
```

Comment: It is weird, because I am adding the readonly as: `taskNotes.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");` I don't know why it is a capital. Also, the JS didn't work for me :/

Comment: Anyway to add it from code-behind? I think the JS is failing :/

Comment: Same thing. Not working still :/ I give up. Thanks for the help

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Are you wrapping that in a doc ready function? And is that element part of the dom on page load? Also take a look at this fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/mzbgdf89/](http://jsfiddle.net/mzbgdf89/). It works...

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I added an alternative, and I was wrong about the case on `readOnly`--jquery doesn't seem to care if the case matches or not. Take a loot [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mzbgdf89/1/) to see the prevent focus in action.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to mention it is inside an UpdatePanel hence why the original code didn't work.

Comment: I +1 and accepted your second solution which worked for me. Silly me. I totally forgot about the updatepanel. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge - Glad to help. :) I updated the answer to have the first option working as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.taskNotes').keydown(function (e) {    
    if ($(this).attr('readonly') === 'readonly' && e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

You need to remove the "input" from the selector.  It is a textarea. 
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/918h49xn/2/)

To add the readonly attribute you can use:

```
$('.taskNotes').prop("readonly", true);
```

or

```
$('.taskNotes').attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

Depending on your jQuery version.

Comment: You can try to remove the camel-case attribute before adding it again.  
$('.taskNotes').removeAttr("readOnly");
 Seems hacky but I would need to see the code to give a better answer

Comment: I totally forgot to say it is inside an updatepanel and that's why the code isn't working. I +1 your code though because it is a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you use ASP.Net, you want to use TextBox Server Controls.

Disabled TextBox generate **disabled** instead of **readonly**. It is more suitable for your scenario.

The way you are doing is not standard in ASP.Net, and it is really fragile. You can read [Disabled and read-only controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12).

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="SubmitButton">
    <asp:TextBox ID="MyTextArea" TextMode="multiline"
        Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="SubmitButton" Text="Submit"
        OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
</asp:Panel>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTextArea.Enabled = false;
}
```